# "Missing Type Specifier" Error in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++

The following line of code

```
int translateCorners(IpPairVec &matches, const CvPoint src_corners[4], CvPoint dst_corners[4]);
```

causes this error

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Are the types of the parameters defined?

Comment: Have you included the proper header files here `IpPairVec` and `CvPoint` have been defined?  The error you're getting often arises when a type name isn't in scope.

Comment: What are the definitions of `IpPairVec` and `CvPoint`?

Comment: Show the surrounding source lines and the complete error message. This error message is not from this line.

Comment: I guess the error is from the previous line. try commenting this code and run. If it gives same error, then you know where to look for problems.

Comment: Yes, they are defined

'CvPoint' is a class in OpenCV ,,, 
'IpPairVec' is a vector of a class in my package

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` and the proper `#include`'s at the top of the file?